Extract and process substring between varying numbers of delimiters in a variable length string
I have a table dates with a column SENTDATE where each row has a varying number of dates in it, separated by a semi colon (;). The dates are currently in the format YYYYMMDD - for example:
20240529;20240626;20240626;20240626;20240626;20240626
20240530;20240620
20240605
20240523;20240523

I'm attempting to convert each of these dates into the format DD/MM/YYYY and keep them delimited by the semicolon so they look like this:
29/05/2024;26/06/2024;26/06/2024;26/06/2024;26/06/2024
30/05/2024;20/06/2024

Unfortunately, I am using SQL Server 2005, so in order to change the formats I need to use SUBSTRING and then combine the different portions of the dates, interspersed with forward slashes:
SUBSTRING(SENTDATE, 1, 4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(SENTDATE, 5, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(SENTDATE, 7, 2)

but that's no issue.
Would you know of a way of being able to process each date between the semi colons? I'm assuming it'll be some sort of split and then recombination of the string?
I haven't actually tried anything here. I could use PARSENAME but I have no clue how to do that with varying numbers of delimiters.
Thank you.

Storing a delimited string in the database is a bad idea. This should be stored as a row per value and using a date/datetime datatype not any kind of string

@MartinSmith Agreed, but these tables were designed and created in the early 2000s - nothing I can do to change it now unfortunately.

There are a whole bunch of questions and answers out there on how to split strings and how to combine them again... e.g. just a quick search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Are you really still using SQL Server 2005 as well? That version reached end of life back in 2016; it is long past the time you implemented your upgrade plan you finalised around a decade ago. 2005 lacks support a lot of features taken for granted now a days as they've been around for a decade or more.

If you were on a modern, supported version of SQL Server you'd probably have access to STRING_SPLIT() and STRING_AGG().

You should really change the schema of your table to comply with basic database normalisation rules. However, if you have to deal with this poor schema you can do the following:
Sample Data and Query
DECLARE @t TABLE (Id INT , SENTDATE VARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO @t (Id , SENTDATE)
VALUES 
 ( 1 , '20240529;20240626;20240626;20240626;20240626;20240626')
,( 2 , '20240530;20240620')
,( 3 , '20240605')
,( 4 , '20240523;20240523');


WITH CTE AS 
(
     SELECT A.Id  
         , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) , CAST(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS DATETIME) , 103) AS SENTDATE  
     FROM  
     (
         SELECT Id,  
             CAST ('<Row>' + REPLACE(SENTDATE, ';', '</Row><Row>') + '</Row>' AS XML) AS Data  
         FROM  @t
     ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/Row') AS Split(a)
 )
SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CAST(SENTDATE AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM CTE 
         WHERE ID = t.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM CTE t
GROUP BY ID

Output
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                               List_Output                               |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |  29/05/2024; 26/06/2024; 26/06/2024; 26/06/2024; 26/06/2024; 26/06/2024 |
|  2 |  30/05/2024; 20/06/2024                                                 |
|  3 |  05/06/2024                                                             |
|  4 |  23/05/2024; 23/05/2024                                                 |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Note
I am pretty sure that concepts like FOR XML PATH,  CROSS APPLY and CTE were introduced in SQL Server 2005, so this solution should work for you.

@MartinSmith oh yes it rings a bell. I will update my solution to use datetime instead, it should work with Datetime too.

Thank you very much - this was the knowledge needed. I'd upvote it but I don't have the reputation to do so just yet, but with a bit of jigging and amending to work with my dataset this worked - thanks!

@MeltedMetal its ok Im glad that it help. You can accept my answer, this will help other users too.

Please try the following solution that is using tokenization via SQL Server's XML and XQuery.
It will work starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards.
Notable points:

CROSS APPLY is converting input string into XML for tokenization.
XQuery .query() method converting individual date values into a desired format in the FLWOR expression.
XQuery .value() method in the SELECT clause is reverting XML back to a string.

SQL
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SENTDATE VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (SENTDATE) VALUES 
('20240529;20240626;20240626;20240626;20240626;20240626'),
('20240530;20240620'),
('20240605'),
('20240523;20240523');

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ';';

SELECT t.*, c
    , REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r)').value('.','VARCHAR(1000)'), SPACE(1), @separator) AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(SENTDATE, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML).query('<root>{
        for $x in /root/r/text()
        return <r>{concat(substring($x,7,2),"/", substring($x,5,2),"/",substring($x,1,4))}</r>
    }</root>')) AS t1(c);

Output



Id
SENTDATE
result




1
20240529;20240626;20240626;20240626;20240626;20240626
29/05/2024;26/06/2024;26/06/2024;26/06/2024;26/06/2024;26/06/2024


2
20240530;20240620
30/05/2024;20/06/2024


3
20240605
05/06/2024


4
20240523;20240523
23/05/2024;23/05/2024



